# Elasticsearch is not generating numeric tokens

Tags: elasticsearch

I am having trouble getting Elasticsearch to generate proper tokens on phrases such as `15 pound chocolate cake`. When performing and `fielddata_field` query on that field it will produce something along the results of:

`pou
poun
pound
cho
choc
choco
chocol
chocola
chocolat
chocolate
cak
cake`

I don't see the numbers in there at all. I have tried several different combinations of analyzer options to no avail. Below is my mappings:

`{
  "settings" : {
    "index" : {
      "analysis": {
         "filter": {
            "nGram_filter": {
               "type": "edge_ngram",
               "min_gram": 3,
               "max_gram": 20
            },
            "my_word": {
                "type":"word_delimiter",
                "preserve_original": "true"
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "nGram_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "standard",
               "filter": [
                  "standard",
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding",
                  "my_word",
                  "nGram_filter"
               ]
            },
            "whitespace_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding"
               ]
            }
         }
      }}
  },
  "mappings": {
    "categories": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {"type": "text"},
        "sort": {"type": "long"},
        "search_term":{"type":"text","analyzer": "nGram_analyzer","search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer", "fielddata":true}
      }
    }
  }
}`

I have tried an `nGram` filter like:

`"nGram_filter": {
    "type": "edge_ngram",
    "min_gram": 3,
    "max_gram": 20,
    "token_chars": [
      "letter",
      "digit",
      "punctuation",
      "symbol"
    ]
  }`

Also setting `"generate_number_parts": "true"` `"generate_word_parts": true` on the `word_delimiter` did not help.

**EDIT**
I got it working by changing the `min_gram` size to 2 but I was hoping to keep it at 3. I am wondering if there is a way to maintain an gram size of 3 but also keep the numbers as is?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is as expected. It is not an issue with numeric tokens but with the term length. Even if you had a string with 1 or 2  chars, it would have been filtered out as well.

> [min_gram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html#_configuration_16) : Minimum length of characters in a gram. Defaults to 1

Any token with less number of characters than the min gram will be filtered out

Hence, 15 is getting filtered out in this case.

Comment: Is there an alternative to accomplish what I want that you know of?

Comment: Any specific reason for not changing min_gram size to 2 ?